# Cannot figure out how to use getchar(); in C

Tags: c, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
    char F,C;

    printf("Do you have a Fever? y/n\n");
    F = getchar();

    printf("Do you have a runny nose or cough? y/n\n");
    C = getchar();


    printf("Here are the results you input:\n");
    printf("Do you have a fever?");
    putchar(F);

    printf("\nDo you have a runny nose or cough?");
    putchar(C);

    return 0;
}
```

The code inputs results from first `getchar();` and then exits without waiting for more input.  Why is that?

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. Read its documentation (`man getchar` or equivalent) to see why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unlike some other Internet forums you may know, Stack Overflow is not a discussion site, nor is it homework help site. It is a **question**-and-**answer** site. Users such as yourself ask questions and other users attempt to answer them. What is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `while` loop after each `getchar()` if you want to process only one character

```
printf("Do you have a Fever? y/n\n");
F = getchar();
while((F = getchar()) != EOF && F != '\n') // This will eat up all other characters
    ;

printf("Do you have a runny nose or cough? y/n\n");
C = getchar();
while((C = getchar()) != EOF && C != '\n')
    ;
```

Comment: And what if the user enters a blank line? Or worse, types ctrl-D or ctrl-Z or whatever the key is for EOF.

Comment: Note that you'll want to put the while loops after you use F and C or they'll be reassigned to the other chars they eat up in the loops. (I know that's obvious to you experts out there but adding the clarification for n00bs like me.)

Comment: Use a variable other than `C` or `F` in the `while` loops.  And, preferably, factor the loops out into a function.

Comment: Using `&&` rather than `&` is more idiomatic here.

Answer (score 11):

First, `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  This is so it can return any valid character (as a value 0..255 for systems where CHAR_BIT is 8) and a separate value (usually -1) as EOF.

Second, when users type an answer, the information contains the character (Y or N, you hope) plus a newline.  There could be leading blanks; there could be trailing garbage.

So, your F probably gets the first character; the C reads the newline, not waiting for more input.

If you want to read lines and process each in turn, use `fgets()` to read the line and `sscanf()` to parse the result.  Or use a function to encapsulate similar processing, such as the `get_answer()` function below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int get_answer(void);    /* Declare in a header? */

int get_answer(void)
{
    int c;
    int answer = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (answer == 0 && (c == 'y' || c == 'n'))  // Upper-case?
            answer = c;
        /* ?check for garbage here and complain? */
    }
    return answer;
}

int main(void)
{
    int F,C;

    printf("Do you have a Fever? y/n\n");
    F = get_answer();

    printf("Do you have a runny nose or cough? y/n\n");
    C = get_answer();

    printf("Here are the results you input:\n");
    printf("Do you have a fever? %c\n", F);
    printf("Do you have a runny nose or cough? %c\n", C);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that newlines go at the end of outputs, in general.  You could omit them from the prompt messages so that the input appears on the same line as the prompt in an interactive session.
The calling code does not really handle EOF properly — where the uses triggers an EOF condition (by typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd> for example) before entering any data.  The code in `get_answer()` is OK; the code in `main()` should test for a zero return.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

It's because when you press Enter, after answering the first question, the enter key gets stored in the next variable C.
To correct it just write another getchar to eat up the extra Enter.

It should be :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
char F,C;

printf("Do you have a Fever? y/n\n");
F = getchar();

getchar(); /* takes the enter key */

printf("Do you have a runny nose or cough? y/n\n");
C = getchar();

getchar(); /* takes the enter key */

printf("Here are the results you input:\n");
printf("Do you have a fever?");
putchar(F);

printf("\nDo you have a runny nose or cough?");
putchar(C);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you enter a character ,it is stored in F,then when you press enter,it is stored in stdin buffer and when next getchar() comes it reads it's input from the stdin buffer ,for this use fflush(stdin) before every getchar() you use.